# cordova build failed for both android and ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova

### Environment

- (1)MacOS: 10.12.5
- (2)node: v8.1.4
- (3)cordova: 7.0.1
- (4)cordova platform ls

  > android 6.2.3
  >
  > ios 4.4.0

### steps

Following http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html, Create your first Cordova app.

### cordova requirements

`Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-24,android-N,android-23,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,android-18,android-17,android-16,android-15,android-14
Gradle: installed /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1-milestone-1/bin/gradle
Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 8.3.3
ios-deploy: not installed
ios-deploy was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.9.0 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy into your path, or do 'npm install -g ios-deploy'
CocoaPods: installed
Error: Some of requirements check failed`

#### sudo npm install -g ios-deploy --unsafe-perm=true

### cordova requirements

`Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-26,android-25,android-24,android-N,android-23,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,android-18,android-17,android-16,android-15,android-14
Gradle: installed /Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1-milestone-1/bin/gradle
Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 8.3.3
ios-deploy: installed 1.9.1
CocoaPods: installed`

### cordova build (or cordova build android)

`ANDROID_HOME=/Users/open/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home
Error: spawn EACCES`

### cordova build ios

`BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Copy\ www\ directory /Users/open/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-fqxzydxnjuyjjobwofitkplrpyef/Build/Intermediates/HelloWorld.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/open/NodeProjects/cordova-projects/hello/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,HelloWorld.xcworkspace,-scheme,HelloWorld,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/open/NodeProjects/cordova-projects/hello/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/open/NodeProjects/cordova-projects/hello/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch`

*How to correct the problems?*

Comment: if you are on Ubuntu/Linux then add +rx permission to cordova project folder and check

Comment: @pro_cheats thank you. I 'm on macos. I tried +rx to project folder, no effect.

Comment: need help urgently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the trigger, the android studio is a 3.0 preview version, and the gradle is 4.1 milestone-1. The key point is that gradle has no execute right!

`MacOS:~ open$ cd "/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1-milestone-1/bin/"
MacOS:bin open$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r--  1 open  staff  5286 Jul  2 11:37 gradle
-rw-r--r--  1 open  staff  2250 Jul  2 11:37 gradle.bat
MacOS:bin open$ sudo chmod a+x gradle`
 
then execute commands:`cordova build` , everything works.